# Consuming an API and listing items in Ionic/Angular

Tags: angular, rest, api, ionic2

So i've been trying to list some items fetched from an API. So far i managed to get the data from the API and .map it. But i haven't been able to actually make it show up on screen. This is what i have on my app.Component:

```
onGet(){
this.MenuServiceProvider.getMenus().subscribe((menus: any[]) => {
  this.menuList = menus;
  console.log("sucess : " + this.menuList);
}
); }
```

The console.log is returning me [object object], which i find weird.

```
getMenus() {
return this.http.get('ApiURL').map(
  (response : Response) => {
    const menus = response.json();
    return menus;
  }
)}}
```

This is what's getting the API o menu-service.ts. Can't show the API because it's private stuff, but it consists of a "data" string holding other strings like "title" and "icon".

```
<ion-menu  [content]="content">
```

```
<button ion-button clear class="user-button">
   <img class="user-icon" src="../assets/img/user-icon.png"><span class="user-text">
   Billie Dog</span>
</button>
<div>
  <button ion-button clear class="switch-button">
     <img class="swap-icon" src="./assets/img/switch-icon.png">
   </button>
</div>

<ion-list class="page-list">
  <ion-item *ngFor "let menu of menuList">
    <p> {{menu.data.title}} </p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<div class="main-footer">
<p class="menu-footer"> Versão 1.0</p>
</div>
```

This is the part where i'm calling the data, which i assume is the problem here. I'm fairly new to Angular. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey, how did it go with my answer below, did it solve your issue? :)

Answer (score 2):

You are concatenating with `+`

```ts
console.log("sucess : " + this.menuList);
```

You should use `,` instead:

```ts
console.log("sucess : ", this.menuList);
```

and the reason for why it's not showing in template, is because you have stored your data in `menuList`, not `menus` like you are trying to iterate in template, so it should be:

```html
<ion-list class="page-list">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let menu of menuList"> <!-- Here! -->
      <p> {{menu.data.title}} </p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Right now it's giving me a parser error(unexpected closing tag 'ion-item'). Any ideas? I'm editing the question with the whole html.

Comment: Seems there are something going on in the template, missing some closing tag completely or similar issue. Such an error is thrown when there is something wrong with the HTML markup.

Comment: AAAh, I saw one error now, you were missing `=` in your *ngFor. Try now, added the `=` in my answer :)